# Standards of writing a jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to learn the best practices on jQuery plugin writing, I can't find unified resources for this kind of stuff. Feel free to criticize AND suggest the right way of writing the plugin.

To be specific, what are the non-standard/ugly part of my code as a jQuery plugin?

**UPDATE:** As you can see, I have some skills in writing a jQuery plugin, based on the tutorials I've found on google... I just want to refine it and apply the best practices.

```
/*
    TARGET PLUGIN USAGE 
        $('#selector-intended-as-mainMenu').toroCaseNav(position, collapseWidth)

    PROCESS
        -on Plugin Use
            Create a submenu container based on plugin object inputs and 'toro-caseNav-main' width

        -on Main menu : mouseenter
            Hide 'toro-caseNav-menuLabel' class 
            Shrink main menu width

        -on Main menu : mouseleave
            Show 'toro-caseNav-menuLabel' class
            Bring back main menu original width
*/

+function( $ ){ "use strict";
    
    var ToroCaseNav = function ( element, options ) {
        this.element = element
        this.options = options
        return 
    }
    
    // Plugin Defaults
    //----------------
    ToroCaseNav.defaults = {
        position       : 'left',
        collapseWidth  : '50px'       
    }  

    ToroCaseNav.prototype.justCall = function( ){
       console.log( this.options )
    }

    ToroCaseNav.prototype.subMenuCreate = function( ){
        console.log( this.options )
        this.justCall()
        //var subMenu_width = $(element).width() 
        return    
    }

    ToroCaseNav.prototype.subMenuAppend = function(){  
        console.log( this.options )
        this.subMenuCreate()
        return 
    }
    
    $.fn.toroCaseNav = function( options ){
        var opt = $.extend( {}, ToroCaseNav.defaults, options )

        return this.each( function(){
            var navi = new ToroCaseNav( $(this)[0], opt )
            navi.subMenuAppend()
        })
    }
    
    $.fn.toroCaseNav.defaults = ToroCaseNav.defaults
        
}( window.jQuery )

// Invoke
//--------
$('#sidebar-wrapper').toroCaseNav({ 'position' : 'top' })
```

[Working Code Here!](http://jsfiddle.net/lemnabong/D556j/3/)

Comment: since this link is from the jquery website itself, this is probably about as "unified" as it gets or at least a good place to start  https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/

Comment: Possible duplicate: [extremely-simple-jquery-plugin-tutorial)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638948/extremely-simple-jquery-plugin-tutorial)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really up to you how will you structure your code, I would simplify it a little bit to make it cleaner.

```
/*globals jQuery, console */
(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    var defaults = {
        position       : "left",
        collapseWidth  : "50px"
    };

    var ToroCaseNav = function (element, options) {

        return {
            justCall: function () {
                console.log(options);
            },
            subMenuCreate: function () {
                console.log(options);
            },
            subMenuAppend: function () {
                console.log(options);
            }
        };
    };

    $.fn.toroCaseNav = function (additionalOptions) {
        var options = $.extend({}, defaults, additionalOptions);

        return this.each(function () {
            var nav = ToroCaseNav(this, options);
            nav.subMenuAppend();
        });
    };

    $.fn.toroCaseNav.defaults = defaults;

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several basic jQuery guides in the official jQuery website istself.

- [Basic Plugin](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)
- [UI Widget Factory](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/stateful-plugins-with-widget-factory/)

Another Tutorial at Treehouse

- [Writing jQuery Plugins](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/writing-your-own-jquery-plugins)

I would also suggest you download some plugins and check how others created them

- [jQuery Plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/)

Finally there is the jQuery Api Documentation and the Mozilla Developer Network for JavaScript reference

- [jQuery Api Docs](http://api.jquery.com/)
- [MDN JavaScript Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/JavaScript)